# How to do a multishot in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, game-development

I am trying to simulate a gun in which shoots multiple bullets at the same time(similar to a spread out shot). I am thinking I have to create another bullet array then do the same as I have below but in a different direction.

Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach (GameObject bullet in bullets) 
{
    // Find a bullet that isn't alive
    if (!bullet.alive)
    {
        //And set it to alive
        bullet.alive = true;

        if (flip == SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally) //Facing right
        {
            float armCos = (float)Math.Cos(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver2);
            float armSin = (float)Math.Sin(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver2);

            // Set the initial position of our bullets at the end of our gun arm
            // 42 is obtained by taking the width of the Arm_Gun texture / 2
            // and subtracting the width of the Bullet texture / 2. ((96/2)=(12/2))
            bullet.position = new Vector2(arm.position.X + 42 * armCos, arm.position.Y + 42 * armSin);

            // And give it a velocity of the direction we're aiming.
            // Increae/decrease speed by changeing 15.0f
            bullet.Velocity = new Vector2(
                (float)Math.Cos(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver4 + MathHelper.Pi + MathHelper.PiOver2),
                (float)Math.Sin(arm.rotation - MathHelper.PiOver4 + MathHelper.Pi + MathHelper.PiOver2)) * 15.0f;
        }

        else //Facing left
        {
            float armCos = (float)Math.Cos(arm.rotation + MathHelper.PiOver2);
            float armSin = (float)Math.Sin(arm.rotation + MathHelper.PiOver2);

            //Set the initial position of our bullet at the end of our gun arm
            //42 is obtained be taking the width of the Arm_Gun texture / 2
            //and subtracting the width of the Bullet texture / 2. ((96/2)-(12/2))
            bullet.position = new Vector2(arm.position.X - 42 * armCos, arm.position.Y - 42 * armSin);

            //And give it a velocity of the direction we're aiming.
            //Increase/decrease speed by changing 15.0f
            bullet.Velocity = new Vector2(-armCos, -armSin) * 15.0f;
        }
        return;
    }// End if
}// End foreach
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is using a for loop and incrementing the degree of rotation by a fixed amount.

Here's a pseudo code example.

```
var spawnPoint = new Vector2(x, y);

for (int angle = 45; angle <= 135; angle += 45)
{
    Bullet.ShootInDirection( spawnPoint, MathHelper.ToRadians(angle) );
}
```

This will shoot 3 bullets at `45°`, `90°`, and `135°`. You can tweak the values accordingly to shoot more or less in different angle increments.

**Here's a visual representation.**

[image: Visual Representation]

For future reference, [there is stack exchange website](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to game development and you may have better results when posting these types of questions there.

Comment: would this allow all three bullets to shoot at the same time as well?

Comment: Yes, they will be shot at the same time. It's just a `for` loop.